# subsetting 1-column matrix deletes rownames

Tags: r, matrix, subset

When I try to subset a 1-colum matrix by it's row names the subsetting works but an numeric vector is returned.

can you somehow prevent that behaviour and keep the row names?

```
M<-as.matrix(rnorm(5))
rownames(M)<-LETTERS[1:5]
M
        [,1]
A  0.6250957
B  0.7330598
C -0.7127075
D  0.2162602
E  0.2223444

M <- M[which(rownames(M) != "A")]

M
## [1]  0.7330598 -0.7127075  0.2162602  0.2223444
```

Comment: You have to add drop=FALSE, as your matrix is one column. `M[which(rownames(M) != "A"),,drop=FALSE]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can read about argument `drop` in the help page: `?'['`

```
M[which(rownames(M) != "A"), ,drop=FALSE]
```

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't know you could use drop=FALSE within the square brackets. I saw the question Henrik referred to, but I didn't see how you could add the drop argument to the subsetting, that's why I asked a new question. Thanks for the quick answer! One more thing: I use the matrix in vegdist( ) with na.rm=TRUE which internally seems to convert it back to a vector (while removing NAs) and then complains that it's a vector. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: Ok, sorry just saw the other question again, and yes my original question is a full duplicate, sorry. Any thoughts about vegdist though? It's a distance function form the vegan package but I guess the same behaviour may arise with other functions that have a na.rm argument...

Comment: @user1183277 check the code of `vegdist`. I can also do it for you but what's the point?